# ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'double'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am trying to read a file in hdf format. It was working correctly before but now all of a sudden I am getting the error below:

```
pandas\_libs\writers.pyx in pandas._libs.writers.string_array_replace_from_nan_rep()

ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'double'
```

My code is just as below:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_hdf('p1.hdf')
data
```

I am using Jupyter notebook and on python 3.6. I just cannot understand why I was able to read the file before without any issues and now this error pops up. The different things that I did since the last run was to create a virtual env to run another code and as I experienced this error now,  I reinstalled anaconda but I am still getting this error when reading this file :(

Comment: Got the same problem with the latest version of pandas.
I just created an issue on the tracker : https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have installed the newest pandas version. I had the same issue with the pandas-0.23.4, downgrading it to 0.22.0 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Update the pandas to version 0.24

It was a problem in pandas 0.23 version. But it is sorted out in the latest version of pandas 0.24.1.

Ref: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24404

you can upgrade by

```
pip3 install pandas -upgrade
```

or

```
conda install pandas
```

Comment: I guess you mean `pip3 install --upgrade pandas`