# Fill NA with desired function(mean) after groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with `NaN`. I'd like to fill `NaN`s with grouped mean.

Sample DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'm': ['m1','m1','m1','m2','m2', 'm2'],
                   'cr':[0.5, 0.3, np.nan, 0.4, 0.5, np.nan]
                 })
```

`df['cr'].fillna` with `groupby` `m` and calculate mean of `cr`.

Comment: You could group, transform to list per group, replace in these lists and then explode the lists to get old indices back, although there are probably prettier/shorter ways: `df['cr'] = df.groupby("m").agg(list)["cr"].apply(lambda lst: [l if l==l else np.nanmean(lst) for l in lst]).explode().tolist()`.

Answer (score 3):

After groupby, you can use `apply` on the desired column and use [`pandas.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with `mean` on each group.

```
df['cr'] = df.groupby(['m'])['cr'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id   m    cr
0   1  m1  0.50
1   2  m1  0.30
2   3  m1  0.40
3   4  m2  0.40
4   5  m2  0.50
5   6  m2  0.45
```

Comment: when I apply this on my real dataframe I get `ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long' , TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index`

Comment: @kms, can you tell me, what is the type of `m` and `cr` columns in the real dataframe. use `df.info()` and tell me what is the type of these two columns

Comment: @kms, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51384956/valueerror-buffer-dtype-mismatch-expected-python-object-but-got-double), other users like you have your problem, and answers say you need to update your pandas.